# Model::Save() tries to send and Id to database that doesnt exist

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Im trying to save data to a table in a postgres database using this piece of code:

```
protected $table = 'measurements';

protected $fillable = ['Measurement_Id','Patient_Id', 'Sensor_Id','Measurement_Type'];

public function saveMeasurement($sensor_Id, $patient_Id, $measurement_type){
    $measurement = new Measurement();

    $measurement->Measurement_Id = Str::Uuid();
    $measurement->Patient_Id = $patient_Id;
    $measurement->Sensor_Id = $sensor_Id;
    $measurement->Measurement_Type = $measurement_type;

    try {
        $measurement->save();

        return "Measurement saved";
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        return $e;
    }
```

However im getting this error message:

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "id" of relation "measurements" does not exist

When I look at the request that is sent to the database I see Im also sending and id:

> ("Measurement_Id", "Patient_Id", "Sensor_Id", "Measurement_Type", "id", "updated_at", "created_at")

I have tried recreating the model and migration both don't seem to help.

Comment: are you using postgres?

Comment: @sta yes its a postgres database

Comment: yes my primary key is a uuid @sta

Comment: add this line on your model `$incrementing = false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this two line to you Measurement model.

```
 protected $primaryKey = 'Measurement_Id'; // or null

 public $incrementing = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is assuming that your primary key name is `id`.
You can specify the pk name with     `protected $primaryKey = 'Measurement_Id';`
Also, if your are using uuid disable the increment

```
 public $incrementing = false;
```

doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys